# Comma separated values vs multirow approach for storing data in SQL Server based on performance and handling of data

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2012, relational-database

Scenario: There are 2 tables. Table1 contains users and Table2 contains Hobbies
User can have multiple hobbies(20-40). and number of users is over 100k.

Approach 1. Create a UsersHobby Table with column 1 as UserID and column 2 as Hobbies and store hobbies as comma separated values. It reduces the number of rows. For example it there are 100k users and each has at least 20 hobbies, still number of rows will be 100k. But it violates normalization principles.

Approach 2. Column 1 as UserID and column 2 as hobbies and store new rows for each hobby. In this case total number of rows would be 2 million if there are 100k users, but it follows normalization principles.

Which one is better approach considering performance and ease of handling data?

Comment: Approach 2 would be better. I thinks you should look at this link for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/39724908/7967350his

Comment: ***NEVER EVER*** store more than one value in a single cell! Period. This is against **fundamental** principles of relational design and will cause you endless grief and trouble in the long run. You should definitely stick to the three normal forms of relational design - and putting more than one value into a cell violates the **first normal form** already.....

Comment: @marc_s  I agree but I was little worried about the volume of data.

Comment: The **volume of data** is (almost) the same, you are talking about the structure... @marc_s is completely correct: **Never ever store more than one value per cell!** You should rather think about the **volume of operations** you will need in future to get anything out of this...

Comment: You're completely missing the point of datatypes in your thinking. The hobby field should just just int, instead of maybe varchar(1000) that you would need for storing any kind of separated list. Then you would also need storage space for all the separators etc. Please don't do anything like that.

Comment: Agree with all previous comments, but for completeness I would add - Approach 3. Add a third table for Hobbies (columns HobbyID int and HobbyName string). Your UsersHobby table has the two ID columns (UserID and HobbID) as foreign keys. Enforcing referential integrity means that you're less likely to end up with multiple versions of the same Hobby with slightly different spellings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 2 would be better because of normalization and appropriate indexes. Since you have sql server 2012, you have an option of Non-Clustered Column Store index if your inserts are in less frequency and reading are in high frequency. Non-Clustered ColumnStore index internally applies compression which makes faster IO.

In Approach 2 you can apply Compression in order to have faster IO which will be faster than IO while handling comma-separated values as in approach 1.

But if you have a frequent UI requirement which needs this comma-separated values to shown in UI then you still consider Approach 1 but the drawbacks are your inserts/update will be very slow as you require a custom approach of making data a comma-separated and if you have a normal retrieval then that will be very slow as you might require to un-parse at that time.